# Best implementation for a class that can have different base member implementations

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I would like to have a child class `Handler` that handles multiple callbacks and transfers data from one class to another. However, the base classes `B1` and `B2`can have different implementations for its members.

Below a way to implement the behavior I want. I think there should be a better way but cannot figure it out.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class IBase
{
    public:
        IBase()
        {
            object = new T(*this);    
        };

        ~IBase()
        {
            delete object;
        }

        virtual void ValidateCallback()
        {
        };

        void RxCallback()
        {
           object->RxCallback();
        };

        void Send()
        {
            object->Send();
        };

       T* object;
};

class C1
{
    public:
        virtual void RxCompleteCallback() = 0;

        void RxParse()
        {
            std::cout << "Parse C1" << std::endl;
            RxCompleteCallback();
        };
};

class C2
{
    public:
        virtual void RxCompleteCallback() = 0;

        void RxParse()
        {
            std::cout << "Parse C2" << std::endl;
            RxCompleteCallback();
        };
};

class B1 : public C1
{
    public:
        B1(IBase<B1> &handler )
        {
           ihandler = &handler;
        };

        void DoSomething()
        {
            std::cout << "DoSomething B1" << std::endl;
            ihandler->ValidateCallback();
        };

        void RxCompleteCallback() override
        {
            std::cout << "DoSomething other than B2" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "RxCompleteCallback" << std::endl;
        };

        void RxCallback()
        {
            RxParse();
        };

        void Send()
        {
            DoSomething();
        };

        IBase<B1> * ihandler;
};

class B2 : public C2
{
    public:
        B2(IBase<B2> &handler )
        {
           ihandler = &handler;
        };

        void DoSomething()
        {
            std::cout << "DoSomething B2" << std::endl;
            ihandler->ValidateCallback();
        };

        void RxCompleteCallback() override
        {
            std::cout << "DoSomething other than B1" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "RxCompleteCallback" << std::endl;
        };

        void RxCallback()
        {
            RxParse();
        };

        void Send()
        {
            DoSomething();
        };

        IBase<B2> * ihandler;
};

class Validate
{
    public:
        void CalculateValidation()
        {
            std::cout << "Calculate validation" << std::endl;
        };
};

template <class T>
class Handler : public IBase<T>, public Validate
{
    public:
        void ValidateCallback() override
        {
            std::cout << "ValidateCallback" << std::endl;
            CalculateValidation();
        };

        void Receive()
        {
            IBase<T>::RxCallback();
        };

        void Send()
        {
           IBase<T>::Send();
        }

};

int main()
{
    Handler<B1> handler1;
    handler1.Receive();
    handler1.Send();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    Handler<B2> handler2;
    handler2.Receive();
    handler2.Send();
}
```

Output:

```
Parse C1
DoSomething other than B2
RxCompleteCallback
DoSomething B1
ValidateCallback
Calculate validation

Parse C2
DoSomething other than B1
RxCompleteCallback
DoSomething B2
ValidateCallback
Calculate validation
```

Comment: Your `IBase` class implementation seems to leak memory. I think you are over-complicating things. But to be honest, I don't understand what you want to achieve at all.

Comment: Can you describe what problem you're trying to solve with this design?

Comment: In short: I want to implement multiple communication protocols. The `Handler` class implements common functionality required for all protocols. But the method implementation of the  `B` and `C` classes are depending on the kind of protocol. Basically I want to have a class signature like `class Handler : public T`, where T can be protocol1Handler or protocol2Handler. But that kind of signature is not possible.

Comment: This reminds me of the strategy design pattern, except that you have various strategies at once and have to select the correct one.

Comment: Do you require runtime polymorphism? it's unclear from your example - note that `Handler<B1>` and `Handler<B2>` are distinct types.

Comment: No, the type of protocol and so ‘Handler<B1>’  etc are known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this in C++. It's hard to say what the best way is, it depends on how you will use it, and the example you gave is too simple to recommend a specific way. Normally, I'd say you want to derive your protocol-specific classes from `Handler`, instead of the other way around, so you'd write:

```
class Handler {
public:
    virtual void Receive() {};
    virtual void Send() {};
};

class B1: public Handler {
    virtual void Receive() {
        ...
    }

    virtual void Send() {
        ...
    }
};

int main() {
    B1 handler1;
    handler1.Receive();
    ...
}
```

The main issue here is that you need to use `virtual` member functions here, otherwise the base class doesn't know which derived class's implementation to call. But it does allow you to pass a `Handler *` as an argument to another function, which will then work with any derived class without needing any templating.

Another option is to use the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which would look like:

```
template <typename T>
class Handler {
    void Receive() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->Receive();
    }

    void Send() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->Send();
    }
};

class B1: public Handler<B1>
{
    void Receive() {
        ...
    }

    void Send() {
        ...
    }
};

int main() {
    B1 handler1;
    handler1.Receive();
    ...
}
```

This avoids virtual methods.
It is also quite similar to your `class Handler`, but it has the advantage that it doesn't need the `T *object` member variable.

Comment: Thanks for the helpfull answers. As for the first example. This is how I would normally implement it as well. However, I have to deal with some legacy code. I will have a look later whether I can rewrite it still being compliant with older code. As for the second example. Before my post I was experimenting with this as well but couldn't get it right for down and upcalls. I think that was because my `Handler` was inheriting from `B1` as it is in the current code instead of the other way around. I will test these ideas out and couple it back here!